# A single word describing a person who is impossible to live with

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a single word describing someone who is impossible to live with because of their bad manners?

Such as in the example:

> 'John, my housemate, has terrible manners; he's an awful person and *impossible to live with*.'

I thought about using the words 'unlivable person' but that sounds a bit strange to me and it's not a single word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A person who is hard to put up with may be described as [insufferable.](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=insufferable&pbx=1&oq=insufferable&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=464466l466795l0l467060l12l8l0l3l3l0l227l1492l0.5.3l11l0&biw=1280&bih=670&sei=R3KiTtDlKYfwrQfl6ISAAw) A person who lacks graceful behaviour or acceptable/pleasing social skills is [uncouth.](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=5&gs_id=1i&xhr=t&q=uncouth&pq=4d&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=uncou&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3977ae3c5b92dbcb&biw=1280&bih=713)

Comment: I think this is too broad. You can be insufferable for many different reasons, including being *overly* meticulous.

Comment: @ onomatomaniak: I've stated that the word refers to someone who is "hard to live with". Going by the italicized part of OP's question, it appears to me he is looking for a concise way to express *impossible to live with.*

Comment: That's fair. I'm not saying it's an inapplicable word; in fact, it's quite a good one. I'm just saying it has a meaning that's broader than "impossible to live with because of bad manners".

Comment: @onomatomaniak Huh?  What a strange objection.  Almost every word you can think of (except for precisely defined technical jargon) is “broad”.  The context narrows the meaning.  That’s how language works!

Answer (score 3):

A great word for a habitually messy person is a ***[sloven](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sloven)***.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fond of *[untoward](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/untoward)*

> : difficult to guide, manage, or work with

and *[intractable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intractable)*

> : not easily governed, managed, or directed